# IIS 6 prompts for creditials when on server, but not from client

Tags: iis-6, sharepoint-2007, credentials

I have a MOSS 2007 farm running on windows server 2003 R2 64 bit and IIS 6. When I try to connect to the farm locally on the server, no matter what site, CA or any of the SharePoint web apps I get prompted for creds and when I enter them everything is fine. But, when I connect from my workstation I am not prompted and my windows creditials get passed succesfully.

The web sites directory security in IIS is set to integrated windows auth. I am not using kerberos.

This  happens from all the servers in this sharepoint farm.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Why is it prompting for my creditials on the server, and not on the client?  As far as I can tell it shouldn't be prompting me, but passing my windows creditials.

Comment: Check that the sites are recognized as Intranet Zone sites in the browser on the servers

Comment: Doh, that was it. I should have known that, but I was looking for a bigger problem.       Thanks!!!

Comment: Good to hear, anyone can make that mistake, (i speak from experience) ^_^ Just added an actual answer so we can close this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the sites are recognized as **Intranet Zone** sites in the browser on the servers.

If Internet Explorer recognizes them as *Internet* sites and not *Intranet* sites, single sign on features will not work, and you'll be prompted for credentials